# Where is Mac OS X Debugging Interface

Tags: macos, debugging, unix

I am new to UNIX and Mac OS X systems and wondering how debugging on Max OS X works. I am from Windows world and I am familiar with debugging system in Windows like attaching to a process with DebugActiveProcess, reading/writing memory with Read/WriteProcessMemory and so on...

I don't know if Mac OS X's debugging also woriking like Windows but
I want to know how a debugger in Max OS X communicates with a target process. Can anyone give me some hits of a start point or documents where I should read first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debugging interface on OS X and most Unixes is called [`ptrace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace).

Type `man ptrace` at a command prompt for information on how ptrace communicates between processes, and also have a look at the header at `/usr/include/sys/ptrace.h`

Answer (score 2):

The typical debuggers are gbd and (recently) lldb. Many IDEs on OS X also use these. So.. "`man gdb`" is a good starting point.

As user1118321 mentioned, installing the Xcode toolset would be a good idea, if you've not done so already. It includes compilers, an IDE, debuggers, profilers, and graphical programs for these tools.

Comment: Also, if you're used to using VisualStudio or Eclipse or some other IDE on Windows, you should install Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state which language, or tools you're using, so for the purposes of this answer I'll assume you're using Objective-C with either gcc or clang to compile your code and link it into an executable. If you're using some other language, such as java or ruby, the equivalent from windows probably exists for OS X as well.

In general, unix uses GDB for debugging, and OS X is no different. You won't always attach it to a running process, I find that's more common to start a process in the debugger, although there do exist tools (such as Instruments) that will profile a running process.

If you're using XCode, there's a whole suite of debugging tools built in that use gdb under the hood. I suggest you start reading some of the developer documentation here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/130-Debugging_Applications/debugging_applications.html and then ask around if there's something in particular you want to know about.

If you've installed Xcode, look at all of the applications installed in /Developer/Applications, at a minimum you should find

Xcode - write and debug, design interfaces here
Instruments - profile your application, look for memory leaks
Icon Composer - create slick icons for your applications
Graphics Tools - used to help work with OpenGL and Quartz mainly